# Fetching data one by one from SQLlite databse in android in 3sec interval gap

Tags: android, database, sqlite, handler

I'm creating an app in which I need to display some quotes I already stored in a SQLLite database.
I know how to fetch the data from the database and display it in a `TextView`.
I need to fetch the data one by one in 3 sec interval and display it in a `TextView`.
That means that every 3 seconds, the app should display a quote from the database.

This is my code.
But it's not working.

```
//code to display quotes in a particular interval
handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable runable = new Runnable() 
{
    int currV = 0;
    boolean go = true;
    @Override 
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            if(currV == 21 && go)
                go = false;
            else if(currV == 0 && !go)
                go = true;

            if(go)
            {
                waterquote.setText(quotelist.get(currV).getQuote());
                currV++;
            }
            else
            {
                currV--;
                waterquote.setText(quotelist.get(currV).getQuote());
            }
            //also call the same runnable 
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally
        {
            //also call the same runnable 
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); 
        }
    }
}; 
handler.postDelayed(runable, 3000);
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what is not working in your code?

Comment: i can see only the final data i inserted into app database.displayed Data is not changing.According to my idea and code i need to cycle through all the data once the end of the database reached?May be i need to increase the interval?

Comment: So, you want to cycle through your records one at a time, in 3 secs interval? Sounds like you want to add a 3 s delay after your moveToNext() instruction.

Comment: I need to fetch one data and display it in TextView.Then wait for some interval.let say 3sec if it is suitable.Then after the interval fetch another data,and so on....can u help me?

Comment: You can set up a [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and set its interval to 3000 (3 secs) and its duration to **1000 * record count**. Then in its `onTick()` method, execute the cursor's `moveToNext()` method.